# SQL question from Data Lemur. https://datalemur.com/questions/user-retention

Tags: postgresql

Assume you're given a table containing information on Facebook user actions. Write a query to obtain number of monthly active users (MAUs) in July 2022, including the month in numerical format "1, 2, 3". In order to calculate the active user retention, we need to identify users who were active in both the current month and the previous month.

Hint:

An active user is defined as a user who has performed actions such as 'sign-in', 'like', or 'comment' in both the current month and the previous month.
user_actions Table:
Column Name Type
user_id integer
event_id    integer
event_type  string ("sign-in, "like", "comment")
event_date  datetime

user_actionsExample Input:
user_id event_id    event_type  event_date
445 7765    sign-in 05/31/2022 12:00:00
742 6458    sign-in 06/03/2022 12:00:00
445 3634    like    06/05/2022 12:00:00
742 1374    comment 06/05/2022 12:00:00
648 3124    like    06/18/2022 12:00:00

Example Output for June 2022:
month   monthly_active_users
6   1

This is the code I tried. It's giving me 3 users when it should only be two. There are only 2 users in the month of June, so I'm not sure why the Exists clause is not working.

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM event_date)
FROM user_actions
WHERE event_date BETWEEN '07-01-2022' AND '07-31-2022' AND
EXISTS
(SELECT DISTINCT(user_id)
FROM user_actions
WHERE event_date
BETWEEN '06-01-2022' AND '06-30-2022')

GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM event_date)

Comment: You have to correlate your subquery with main query through user_id: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/niUZaglE).